# Bash select statement with Alphabets as options

Tags: bash, shell, select, case

I am currently coding a menu using the select statement as shown below.

```
options=("Say Hello" "Say Bye" "Say Go Away")
select alphabets in "${options}";
do
     case $REPLY in
        a) echo Hello ;;
        b) echo Bye ;;
        c) echo GoAway; break;;
     esac
done
```

I want the output to show:

```
a) Say Hello
b) Say Bye
c) Say Go away
```

but the output shows numerical numbers as shown below:

```
1) Say Hello
2) Say Bye
3) Say Go away
```

Is there anyway for me to make it such that I get alphabets as the options?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by this:

> ```
> $ help select
> select: select NAME [in WORDS ... ;] do COMMANDS; done
>     The WORDS are expanded, generating a list of words.  The
>     set of expanded words is printed on the standard error, each
>     preceded by a number.  [...]
> ```

I'm afraid what you want is not possible.
The choices will be numbered,
and this behavior is not configurable to make it alphabetic.

If you want to see alphabetic options, you have to implement your own.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't thought select has a help page! Cheers!!